# FTP file size limit

Tags: ftp, files, quota

I have a webhost account, which has a file size limit, so cannot upload my backup file. How can I upload it maybe in more pieces and after that merge pieces on server? I don't have SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

Please check on below links- :

http://linuxpoison.blogspot.in/2008/09/split-and-merge-large-files.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/whats-the-best-way-to-join-files-again-after-splitting-them